# image change on mouse hover on particular part of image

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

```
<img src="C:/Users/ma/Desktop/start_new_coin/rebulid from  scratch/chaptermap/ch01ch01.png"width="453" height="453" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">
<map name="planetmap">
<area shape="poly" coords="172,227,181,224,183,213,189,201,195,193,199,190,199,184,126,93,135,93,123,79,103,96,84,117,68,140,58,162,51,186,48,201,47,214,135,219,130,227,148,227,147,225,151,227,149,223,153,227,153,221,156,225,157,214,160,202,166,190,174,179,176,177,174,174,191,176,192,192,189,189,180,200,174,212,172,224,172,227" alt="Sun" onmouseover="this.src='C:/Users/ma/Desktop/start_new_coin/rebulid from scratch/chaptermap/ch01ch12.png'" width="453" height="453" onmouseout="this.src='C:/Users/ma/Desktop/start_new_coin/rebulid from scratch/chaptermap/ch01ch01.png'" width="453" height="453"/>
</map>
```

I am trying to change image when mouse is over an particular area of image. But it does not change. here is my code. I have tried this but it is not changing on image hover.

Comment: Erm... I don't see the code? Maybe you need to add it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Your code is not yet visible, please edit the post and add the source code.

Comment: possibly [map tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) and [area tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area)

Comment: I have added the code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to the image using `this`, but `this` actually refers to the element that triggers the mouse event which is the `<area>`; an `<area>` tag does not have a `src` attribute which you can set using javascript.

You need to refer to the image differently, for instance using a class or ID:

```
<img src="image1.png" id="image1" width="453" height="453" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">
<map name="planetmap">
    <area shape="poly" coords="..." alt="Sun"
         onmouseover="document.getElementById('image1').src='image2.png'" 
         onmouseout="document.getElementById('image1').src='image1.png'"/>
</map>
```

(and ditch the `width` and `height` attributes on the `<area>` tag as well)

Comment: This worked. Is it possible to make image change according to browser size? I am confused because image map uses co ordinates.

Comment: Is it possible to get dynamic getelement by id instead of 'image1'. if user clicks on an image while hovering that image stays and when he continues hovering again, again the images change and on mouse out this time the changed image shows up instead of image 1

Comment: For a responsive layout, I'd use multiple images that have their own image map defined.

Comment: And what do you mean by 'dynamic getelement by id'? Do you want to use multiple images and dont want to set the ID each time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the image map.
For example :

```
<img src="path/to/picture.gif" width="374" height="162" usemap="#map1" id="image" />
<map name="panneaux">
    <area shape="rect" coords="92,19,261,66" onmouseover="action1()" alt="john" />
</map>
```

Et le js :

```
action1() {
    document.getElementbyId("image").src = "new image";
}
```

Comment: i have tried the onmouseover in my code but it does not work

Comment: Is it possible to make image change according to browser size? I am confused because image map uses co ordinates.

Comment: sorry I have not tested this code... the `coords` are bad